# A man severe he was and stern to view

Tags: meaning-in-context

I think the meaning of this sentence --

> ***A man severe he was and stern to view.***

is he was a severe and stern person.
But I don't understand the grammar rule that this sentence follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my ear your example is poetic and reminiscent of 1800s literature.  I would expect to read it in *Moby Dick.*  It appears to be missing punctuation (a comma after "A man," but the "rules" of punctuation have changed considerably in the last century and a half, so perhaps you've conveyed the sentence accurately.  Either way...

There isn't a perfect interpretation without the context of the sentence (and, even then, it may not be perfect).  But that's the point with poetic language.  It is meant to elicit feelings rather than convey clear facts.

> A man...

That is simple...

> ...severe he was...

Remember that poetic language is more about emotion than fact.  Since the next clause is more physical than psychological, this phrase <s>should</s> could be read to express the man's character and suggests a blunt person, sharp tongued and brusque.  His presence would be commanding or, perhaps, simply noticeable (such as an intrusion).  But it might also suggest physically sharp features: a square jaw, defined cheekbones, square shoulders, and no waist.  Probably not handsome, certainly not gentle.

> ...and stern to view.

This suggests a worker, such as a fisherman, blacksmith, or factory worker.  He isn't smiling and doesn't smile naturally, but appears sombre and sober.  He focuses on his labor, which is necessary to sustain life, but not necessarily to enjoy it.  His reality brooks little fantasy or entertainment.  His eyebrows cast a metaphorical shadow over his eyes.  A child (one of his) might see him as a disciplinarian, even a source of punishment.  An associate would see him as "no nonsense."

*It's important that you understand that, if I'm right and this is a poetic form from the 1800s, the lack of the context (the entire paragraph or surrounding paragraphs) severely hampers our ability to properly explain this sentence.  In short, I could be very wrong in my interpretation.  It would help if we knew where you read the phrase.  What book, article, or story.*

Comment: I found this sentence in one of the exercises of wren and martin.

Comment: @Kshitij Singh This is from "The Village Schoolmaster" by Oliver Goldsmith ( https://allpoetry.com/The-Village-Schoolmaster2) a poem dating from the mid 1700s

Answer (score 0):

"The Village Schoolmaster" by Oliver Goldsmith (1770)

> ...
>   There, in his noisy mansion, skill'd to rule,
>
> The village master taught his little school;
>
> A man severe he was, and stern to view,
>
> I knew him well, and every truant knew;
>
> Well had the boding tremblers learn'd to trace
>
> The days disasters in his morning face;

...

As often in poetry, the aim is to convey much in few words.

"A man severe he was," suggests severity of character, and particularly in context that he was severe with his students. "and stern to view" may mean that he appeared stern, and this is supported by the following lines which speak of how the students tried to read his mood in his face But remember that "view" can also be a verb, and it may mean "he took a stern view of things" or "he looked on life sternly". Indeed it may well mean both at once -- that kind of compressed double meaning is not uncommon in poetry.